# AppsScript GMail API image on body

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm developing an AppScript that will get Gmail's message  and create a Doc on Drive. But in case of mails with embedded images or linked images, I can't get it. The HTML from message.getBody() show just image src like this:

```
<img src="?view=att&amp;th=13f0ae12c4b7998b&amp;attid=0.2&amp;disp=emb&amp;realattid=ii_13f0ae05d6a92117&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" alt="Inline image 1">
```

Does anyone tried this before?

Thanks,